# How to use node-archiver in windows

Tags: node.js, node-archiver

Code from official documentation:

```
// append files from a sub-directory, putting its contents at the root of archive
archive.directory('subdir/', false);
```

How do I need to change 'subdir/' in windows environment：

```
archive.directory('F:/dir', false);
```

But if I write like this, it will give an error。

error: input source must be valid Stream or Buffer instance

Comment: I'm pretty sure `F:/dir` is not a subdirectory. Your code would have to be placed in `F:`

Comment: I want to use absolute path.

Comment: Can't this method use absolute paths?